# Excel - Replace matching column values based on another column set

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is a way to replace values in one column to new values from another column set. Like an auto search and replace confined to a column where the search/replace data is dictated by the column set from another excel file. Specifically here's the situation.

In one column I have old user IDs like so, which can't be sorted because it's a CSV for importing into a website and it has duplicates which each row represent new forum threads & replies etc:

```
7766
7779
7781
7782
7791
7792
```

I need to replace these values with the new correct values.
I have two other columns in another excel file where I have the old member ID numbers next to it's corresponding new member ID number in ascending order, like this:

```
7066    637
7067    638
7068    639
7069    640
7070    641
7071    642
7072    643
```

The topic/thread file I manually used the search and replace function for all members which took a very long time... I'm wondering if there's an automated way to do this for the reply file? which has substantially more data rows.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried vlookup?
=VLOOKUP(C2,[Book2]Sheet1!$B$2:$C$8,2)

Where [Book2] is where your correct or new ID's are.

Comment: I've tried vlookup but not sure how to use the arguments yet as when I do it or use your formula I get the wrong result. So to simply things, if Column G on the 1st sheet represents the author ID (row 1 is not used since it's the column heading),  and column A on the 2nd sheet represents the matching data, and column B on the 2nd sheet represents the replacement value. How would I formulate that? Thank you! EDIT, I THINK THIS WORKED! `=VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet1!A:B,Sheet1!A:A,2)` though I'm not sure what range does.. but hopefully this does the trick

Comment: 95% of the time you will want to use false or 0 for the range parameter. This forces vlookup to return an exact match or an error.

Comment: Using true or 1 will return then closest match in the dataset.

Comment: To correct myself, `=VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)` is what worked in my case. Thank you for the help @WCoaster !